# Postgres Partitioning not working with hibernate if id is bigserial

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, partitioning, postgresql-9.5, database-partitioning

I have partitioned my table in Postgres. So there are 2 tables now :

1. Base table users , with no primary key but using a sequence generator for id column : nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
2. Child table inheriting users

   ```
   CREATE TABLE users_part_2019_01 (
       CHECK (createdon >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
                       AND createdon < '2019-02-01 00:00:00')
   ) INHERITS (users);

   ALTER TABLE users_part_2019_01 ADD CONSTRAINT users1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
   ```

I am inserting data into users table using jpa. In the data model I have used :

```
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

**Getting the following error :**

> "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: The database returned
>   no natively generated identity value; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively
>   generated identity value
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)"

It is working as expected independently with postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution. Instead of  GenerationType.IDENTITY, GenerationType.AUTO is working

Answer (score 0):

In case you are coming here from spring boot (2.2.x +) and using postgresql partitioning, the accepted answer alone is not enough to make it work. Hibernate, in this case, will throw the following:

```
Schema-validation: missing sequence [schema_name.hibernate_sequence]
```

In this case, the hibernate simply wants you to provide the identity generator for the sequence field by passing it as:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "schema_name.generator_sequence_name_seq")
```